# How to build a one-to-many RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, one-to-many, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to RNNs and I want to build a one-to-many RNN using Tensorflow. The "one" input in my model is a vector of 3 coordinates(something like [x0, y0, z0]) and the "many" output I wish to achieve is a sequence of 50 numbers, 1 for each time step.

For example, I give this single point in 3d space like P = [1, 2, 3] and I wish to predict a sequence of 50 numbers, representing the temperature at this point for 50 consecutive time steps.

I searched a lot about some sample codes but I could not find a good one-to-many RNN on the web. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: you can use the Model structure to run with multiple output

Comment: @dtlam26, how do you ensure that the output from each rnn unit in the model chain feeds the hidden output into the next cell?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a RNN where you input 3 features ([x0, y0, z0]) and output a vector of 50 numbers representing temperature over 50 time steps?

In that case, you need to input coordinates for each timestep you want to predict, as the whole idea of RNN's is that they can learn to predict time series by seeing examples of such series. Your data needs to be in the following structure:

Your coordinate data needs to be in a format where you have the x,y,z data for each timestep you wish to predict. If we assume you have 10000 data points, your input data would need to have this shape:

[**10000**, **50**, **3**]

Here **10000** is the amount of data points, **50** is the timestep for each xyz coordinate, and **3** is each of the coordinates in a given timestep.

Your temperature data then needs to have the following shape:

[**10000**, **50**]

Here **10000** is each collection of temperatures over the 50-time steps, and **50** is each of the temperature readings in the timesteps.

In the case that you only want to use 1 coordinate set to predict the 50 timesteps, you could just reshape your data to have the same 50 coordinates in each of the timesteps.

Assuming you have this dataset, you could construct a simple RNN like this:

```
# ----- Define dummy data -----
coordinates = np.random.random([10000, 50, 3]).astype(np.float32)
temps = np.random.rand(10000,50)

# ----- Define RNN model -----
rnn_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
rnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(128))
rnn_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50))

# ----- Compile model -----
rnn_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4))

# ----- Train model -----
history = rnn_model.fit(x=coordinates, y=temps, batch_size=32,epochs=50)
```

You would of course need to change your network structure depending on the task, and you could also experiment with other recurrent layers such as a LSTM layer, but this should give you an idea of the basics.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just can not understand one thing, why the input shape must be [10000,50,3]? Why not [10000,3]? I mean I have a [#number of points,3] matrix where the first column represents the x axis,second represents the y axis and the third represents the z axis. And each row stands for a point.

Comment: That is because a RNN layer expects a set of data points for each timestep you are trying to predict. The reason is that the RNN tries to learn how a change in the coordinates will affect the temperature over time. However if you change your data so that you have the same coordinate reading on each timestep, you might be able to still learn a relationship between the coordinates and the temperature over time. But generally the idea of RNN’s is that you provide it with data for each timestep. You might be able to use a regular neural network for your task if you only have 1 set of xyz coordinat

Comment: Yes, Thanks. Could you please tell me how can I reshape my [10000,3] example to [10000,50,3]?

Comment: Should I stack them up?

Comment: I think you should get to know Numpy which is THE library for matrix operations in Python. If you want to get into RNN's or any form of Neural Networks in Python you need to understand how it works. 

Numpy has a great beginners tutorial here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html

Comment: @MDan Your answer is inaccurate. RNNs can have differently sized inputs and outputs. In One to many RNN, you have one input and indefinite amount of outputs. How this works is that the predictions of a previous cell usually gets passed as input to the next cell, simulating multiple inputs. It is quite possible to learn an accurate mapping function that maps one input to multiple but this can be challenging and require a lot of data.